# Text printing for a text adventure game, with color and other stuff (Python)

Tags: python, beginner, console

I really think there's a better way to do this, but I can't seem to find it. Can you please point me in the right direction?

```
import colorama
import os
from enum import Enum

def clearscreen():
    # Clear the screen
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')

class Color(Enum):
    """
    An Enum for representing escape sequences, that color the terminal, even in 
    Windows, with colorama.

    """
    NATIVE = "\033[m"
    BLACK = "\033[0;30m"
    BLUE = "\033[0;34m"
    GREEN = "\033[0;32m"
    CYAN = "\033[0;36m"
    RED = "\033[0;31m"
    PURPLE = "\033[0;35m"
    BROWN = "\033[0;33m"
    GRAY = "\033[0;37m"
    DARK_GRAY = "\033[1;30m"
    LIGHT_BLUE = "\033[1;34m"
    LIGHT_GREEN = "\033[1;32m"
    LIGHT_CYAN = "\033[1;36m"
    LIGHT_RED = "\033[1;31m"
    LIGHT_PURPLE = "\033[1;35m"
    YELLOW = "\033[1;33m"
    WHITE = "\033[1;37m"

class Dialoge():
    """
    Basic Dialoge class, with various methods.

    """

    def __init__(self):
        colorama.init()

    def important(self, wrap)
        # Print an "I---I"-like line based on the length of the text
        print("I", end="")
        for dash in range(wrap):
            print("-", end="")
        print("I", end="")
        print()

    def tprint(self, message, color, char, rank):
        """
        Print Dialoge to the terminal, with a lot more options

        """

    total = ""

    if rank == 0:
        if char == "NO_CHAR":
            if color != "DEFAULT":
                print(f"{color}{message}{Color.NATIVE.value}")
            else:
                print(f"{message}")
        else:
            if color != "DEFAULT":
                print(f"{color}[{char}]:{Color.NATIVE.value} {message}")
            else:
                print(f"[{char}]: {message}")
    else:
        if char == "NO_CHAR":
            if color != "DEFAULT":
                if rank == 1:
                    print(f"{color}! - {message} - !{Color.NATIVE.value}")
                elif rank == 2:
                    total = f"!! -- {message} -- !!"
                    print(color, end="")
                    self.important(len(f"!! -- {message} -- !!") - 2)
                    # When evaluating the length of a string, rest -2 for the "/r/n".
                    print(total)
                    self.important(len(f"!! -- {message} -- !!") - 2)
                    print(Color.NATIVE.value, end="")
                elif rank == 3:
                    clearscreen()
                    print(color, end="")
                    total = f"!!! --- {message} --- !!!"
                    self.important(len(f"!!! --- {message} --- !!!") - 2)
                    print(total)
                    self.important(len(f"!!! --- {message} --- !!!") - 2)
                    print(Color.NATIVE.value, end="")
            else:
                if rank == 1:
                    print(f"! - {message} - !")
                elif rank == 2:
                    total = f"!! -- {message} -- !!"
                    self.important(len(total) - 2)
                    print(total)
                    self.important(len(total) - 2)
                elif rank == 3:
                    clearscreen()
                    total = f"!!! --- {message} --- !!!"
                    self.important(len(total) - 2)
                    print(total)
                    self.important(len(total) - 2)
        else:
            if color != "DEFAULT":
                if rank == 1:
                    print(f"! - {color}[{char}]:{Color.NATIVE.value} {message} - !")
                elif rank == 2:
                    total = f"!! -- {color}[{char}]:{Color.NATIVE.value} {message} -- !!"
                    self.important(len(f"!! -- [{char}]: {message} -- !!") - 2)
                    print(total)
                    self.important(len(f"!! -- [{char}]: {message} -- !!") - 2)
                elif rank == 3:
                    clearscreen()
                    total = f"!!! --- {color}[{char}]:{Color.NATIVE.value} {message} --- !!!"
                    self.important(len(f"!!! --- [{char}]: {message} --- !!!") - 2)
                    print(total)
                    self.important(len(f"!!! --- [{char}]: {message} --- !!!") - 2)
            else:
                if rank == 1:
                    print(f"! - [{char}]: {message} - !")
                elif rank == 2:
                    total = f"!! -- [{char}]: {message} -- !!"
                    self.important(len(total) - 2)
                    print(total)
                    self.important(len(total) - 2)
                elif rank == 3:
                    clearscreen()
                    total = f"!!! --- [{char}]: {message} --- !!!"
                    self.important(len(total) - 2)
                    print(total)
                    self.important(len(total) - 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your color code is not portable. Instead, try using something like the [`termcolor` package](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/) which handles the complexity of colors for you. It seems like you've imported an initialized `colorama`, but aren't using that. That is a fine alternative. Just don't try doing it yourself (your `Color` enum)! With `termcolor` you can make help functions that abstract away color names:

```
print_warning = lambda x: cprint(f'warning: {x}', 'yellow')

# Later in your code
print_warning('something went wrong')
```

Instead of:

```
print('I', end='')
for dash in range(wrap):
    print('-', end='')
print('I', end='')
print()
```

Why not:

```
print('I' + ('-' * wrap) + 'I')
```

Or you could pull it out into a variable to make it a bit cleaner:

```
divider = '-' * wrap
print(f'I{divider}I')
```

`tprint` is way too confusing for me to follow. Perhaps try breaking it into several methods instead of one method whose behavior changes drastically depending on the parameters provided.